# How to use mutate function in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to create plot in R. For that I first need to mutate a new column called "export_ratio". I have tried using the below code, but I am getting error as given below the code. Can someone please help?

```
eu_macro %>% 
  mutate(export_ratio = (exports/gdp)*100) %>% 
  filter(year>1995) %>% 
  filter(country %in% c("Germany","France","Spain","Sweden")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year,export_ratio))+
  geom_line(aes(color=country))
```

**Error**: Problem with `mutate()` column `export_ratio`.
i `export_ratio = (exports/gdp) * 100`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator

Sample Data:

[image]

Comment: It is hard to troubleshoot without some sample data. However, have a look at `"1" / 5`. The error message informs that there is at least 1 non-numeric variable being manipulated, have a look at the class of `exports` and `gdp`.

Comment: @DonaldSeinen - Added the sample data. and yes "Exports" column is "chr". How do I fix that?

Comment: @ShubhamPatil You can change the datatype by eu_macro %>% mutate(exports = as.numeric(exports))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `exports` variable is a character type, so it does not make sense to do `(exports/gdp)`. So, you can convert it to numeric:

```
eu_macro %>% 
  mutate(export_ratio = (as.numeric(exports)/gdp)*100) %>%
```